# Почему qt creator выделяет правильные строки как ошибки?

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qtcreator

Перешел на последний убунту, установил qt с репозитория. Я создал проект с++, он компилируется, но сама ide почему то выделяет правильные строки как ошибка, как это исправить ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пробовали тут почитать https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-cmake.html?

Answer (score 1):

Такое поведение бывает при установке из репозитория Ubuntu - некорректно работает модуль `ClangCodeModel` который вы можете отключить: перейдите в меню `Справка -> О модулях...`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но я вам рекомендую удалить эту версию Qt и установить с [официального сайта](https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer?hsCtaTracking=99d9dd4f-5681-48d2-b096-470725510d34%7C074ddad0-fdef-4e53-8aa8-5e8a876d6ab4)